# How to join two tables which one has two samples of the other one (and we want to see them all in the final table)

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables in my SQL database, `Team` and `Match`. Each match has two team ids - one for the `host_team` and one for the `guest_team`.

My question is: how could I join these two tables to have the data of the matches, with the full data of both `host_team` and `guest_team` in one unique dataset?

Team:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 2 | y |

Match:

| id | host_id | guest_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

Final dataset:

| match_id | host_id | host_name | guest_id | guest_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | x | 2 | y |

Comment: You can either `join` the tables or use a `correlated subquery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just left join Team to Match twice

```
SELECT 
  match.match_id
, match.host_id
, host.name AS host_name
, match.guest_id
, guest.name AS guest_name
FROM Match AS match
LEFT JOIN Team AS host ON host.id = match.host_id
LEFT JOIN Team AS guest ON guest.id = match.guest_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Either way you need to query the `Team` table twice, one way is to use an inline-select correlated on the appropriate `id`

```
select m.Id as match_id,
    m.host_id,
    (select name from Team t where t.id=m.host_id) host_name,
    m.guest_id
    (select name from Team t where t.id=m.guest_id) guest_name,
from Match m
```